# Issue in updating the package /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I was having an issue in installing package on Release:20.04, running server version, codename: focal, I tried with sudo apt-get update but still, it was not working and I then read on StackOverflow and tried the following

Step-1:Remove the file sources.list

```
sudo rm -fr /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Step-2:Run the update process. It will create the file again

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now /etc/apt/sources.list file is deleted and I am unable to install any package.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

copy a new file from **/usr/share/doc/apt/examples/sources.list**:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/doc/apt/examples/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list
```